# What keyboard key is the safest to press to wake a computer from screen saver?

Tags: keyboard, screensaver

Just wondering, any OS, any computer. What if I accidentally double-tap the key? Or what if the screensaver wasn't on? I'm guessing <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> are quite bad, along with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and hitting the middle of the keyboard with a fist.

Which one is the safest? <kbd>Shift</kbd>?

Comment: Personally I use ALT

Comment: Personally I use either Alt or an arrow key. Arrow keys seem pretty harmless imho.

Comment: besides the above two comments, and this isn't an answer at all, but (certainly if there's a mouse) i'd knock the mouse first before a keyboard key as it just seems so easy. In my youth I threw a tennis ball at the keyboard from a distance(sometimes to intentionally hit SPACE when scandisk ran on win9X to quit it). Nowadays i've used arrow but if ALT works I might give that a shot! though alt is a bit near space.   I haven't really rtied modifier keys ctrl/shift/alt great if they work. often I did arrow key and if that doesn't wake it (it's standby) so power button.

Comment: Any examples where `alt` is better than `shift`, or vice versa?

Comment: If you don't know if this or that key is safe, it implies(rightly) that you(understandably and justifiably!) don't know the status of the screen(e.g. what is selected).. so you're not going to know it after you push a safe or relatively safe key either.  I always check the screen after and see the status of it. IF you -need- something to be *THAT* safe like more safe than an arrow key, then you are being unsafe after you hit the key! (and there is no reason why that time should be any different to coming to the computer when there is no screensaver or just using it normally).

Comment: What about `Caps Lock` or `Num Lock`?